# sphinx collation when mysql collation is utf8_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, sphinx, collation

Which collation would be better to set in Sphinx config file if utf8_unicode_ci is used in searchable MySQL table? I'd like to be able to sort searched data taking in notice umlauts (accents), case insensitive.

P.S. I'm reading http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.6/collations.html at the moment, but not everything is clear to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use  in source configuration sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8 , in index configuration charset_type = utf-8 and you need to add to the default charset_table utf codes for umlauts, for example, check http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=charset_tables

Comment: Thank you. Is it obligatory to use sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8? Did you encounter any problems without it? Should't 'collation_server' be set? Or just utf-8 charset_table should be fully overwritten?

Comment: set names utf8 is enough from what I saw. Without it you will have problems if you try to grab utf data. umlauts chars needs to be added to the exist ones in charset_table